# Error: failed to start the transport 'WebSockets' in Blazor Server App in .NET 6

Tags: asp.net, amazon-ec2, websocket, blazor-server-side

I am deploying a Blazor server app on an EC2 instance and also using application load balancer , and when I route to another page, I get an error shown in the browser console.

I am using Nginx but when I try to do it through the direct ip of instance it works perfectly and when I try it through loadbalancer dns  I get the same error.

This is the error:

[image]

I tried different methods, but didn't find any solution - please help me solve this.

Comment: If you are using Blazor Server you are using Signal R. Always.